# Why uboot x86_64 can not boot alpine vmlinuz-virt, reset after boot

Tags: boot, qemu, boot-loader, u-boot, alpine-linux

qemu-x86_64 [uboot.rom](https://github.com/wenerme/alpine-image/blob/master/artifacts/uboot/qemu-x86_64/u-boot.rom?raw=true) with Alpine's virt

get vmlinux

```bsh
wget https://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.12/releases/x86_64/netboot/{vmlinuz,initramfs}-virt
```

now boot qemu

```bsh
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -smp 2 -nographic -bios u-boot.rom \
  -kernel vmlinuz-virt \
  -initrd initramfs-virt \
  -append 'root=/dev/ram console=ttyS0'
```

```
# load kernel
qfw load
# boot according to last command output
zboot 0000000001000000 5632a0 0000000004000000 453acb
```

I expected the kernel booking message, but seems uboot reseted

```
Valid Boot Flag
Setup Size = 0x00004000
Magic signature found
Using boot protocol version 2.0d
Linux kernel version 5.4.43-1-virt (buildozer@build-3-12-x86_64) #2-Alpine SMP Thu, 28 May 2020 20:13:48 UTC
Building boot_params at 0x00090000
Loading bzImage at address 100000 (5649056 bytes)

U-Boot SPL 2020.04 (Aug 10 2020 - 14:50:54 +0000)
CPU: x86_64, vendor AMD, device 663h
Trying to boot from SPI
Jumping to 64-bit U-Boot: Note many features are missing


U-Boot 2020.04 (Aug 10 2020 - 14:50:54 +0000)

CPU:   QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
DRAM:  1 GiB
Incorrect expansion ROM header signature 4daa
Model: QEMU x86 (I440FX)
Net:   e1000: 52:54:00:12:34:56
       
Warning: e1000#0 using MAC address from ROM
eth0: e1000#0
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
starting USB...
No working controllers found
USB is stopped. Please issue 'usb start' first.
scanning bus for devices...

Device 0: unknown device

Device 0: unknown device
```

What's wrong with the setup? How can I boot vmlinuz-virt by using u-boot ?

**EDIT**

load from ide shows the same message

```bsh
# a bootable image
qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -m 1024 -accel hvf -hda images/virt/alpine.qcow2 

# using uboot can not boot
qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -m 1024 -bios artifacts/uboot/qemu-x86_64/u-boot.rom -hda images/virt/alpine.qcow2
```

uboot command

```
load ide 0 ${kernel_addr_r} /vmlinuz-virt
load ide 0 ${ramdisk_addr_r} /initramfs-virt
zboot ${kernel_addr_r} - ${ramdisk_addr_r} ${filesize}
```

after display `Loading bzImage at address`, next message is `U-Boot 2020.04 (Aug 10 2020 - 14:50:54 +0000)`

**EDIT2**
i386 works, this is related to uboot x86_84

Comment: [The usage example](https://github.com/wenerme/alpine-image/tree/master/artifacts/uboot) from your uboot.rom source uses the `-hda` option to specify a disk image for the VM, and not the `-kernel`, `-initrd` and `-append` options. Looks like those options may be in conflict: if you want to use u-boot, then you may have to let u-boot load the kernel from the disk image, and not try to supply it with `-kernel`, because that option seems to expect a regular PC BIOS, not u-boot.

Comment: @telcoM  I tried load from ide, but same result